# KineticJS Stage height vs Layer height

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm having a couple of issues with my application, I'm using the KineticJS library for some animations.

Here's the issue I'm having.

[image: KineticJS issue]

I haven't figured out why the colors screw up when it goes outside this "box", I'm using 2 layers, 1 for the text and 2nd for the balls.

I checked the source and I see that the canvas width and height attributes aren't proportional to the stage width and height attributes.

```
<div class="kineticjs-content" role="presentation" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 2133px; height: 1011px;">
<canvas width="1919" height="909" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 2133px; height: 1011px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></canvas>
<canvas width="1919" height="909" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 2133px; height: 1011px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></canvas>
</div>
```

This is how I create a stage to make it full-screen:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});
```

And I create a layer by doing this:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
```

Would anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I had same problem sometimes when running application on localhost. Try to clear cache (open dev console) and reload.

Comment: That did indeed seem to solve the issue, although I'm not running this on localhost, thanks!

Comment: That did not solve the issue, it runs fine on Firefox, Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m bugs out.